# Uploading a spreadsheet file on Google Drive in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am able to upload an NSMutableString string (separated by commas) as a CSV file to Google Drive in Swift. However, I want to save it as a Google Spreadsheet.

Apparently, they have the "convert" property in Objective-C when you use queryForFilesInsertWithObject method. However, I couldn't find the Swift version of this. I created my query as such:

let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesCreateWithObject(metadata, uploadParameters: uploadParameters)

Since there is no `q.convert` property, I tried both of the following statements:

```
query.q = "convert=true"
query.q = "convert=YES"
```

However, none of them worked.

I have also tried to have mimeType as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` and `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` and they didn't help either.

My code is as follows:

```
let data = NSMutableString()
var i = 0
repeat {
       data.appendString("\(measures[i]), \(SegmentedControlChoiceValues[i])\n")
       i += 1
} while i < measures.count
let dataAsString = data as String

let metadata = GTLDriveFile()
metadata.mimeType = "text/csv"
metadata.name = "Subject01.bar"

let dataToUpload = dataAsString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let uploadParameters = GTLUploadParameters(data: dataToUpload!, MIMEType: metadata.mimeType)
let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesCreateWithObject(metadata, uploadParameters: uploadParameters)

query.q = "convert=true"

Constants.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler:  { (ticket, insertedFile , error) -> Void in

     if error == nil {
        print("File Saved: " + metadata.name)
        success(createdFileID: insertedFile.identifier)
     } else {
        print("An error occurred" + error.description)
        success(createdFileID: "")
     }
})
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the file first, files in the Drive API are represented by the GTLDriveFile class. The contents of the file must be fetched or uploaded separately.

You need to convert it into a portable format. When you create a new file, you specify both the initial metadata with  [GTLDriveFile](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files#additional_options) and the content with GTLUploadParameters. Set `convert property to yes` for `GTLQueryDrive`

Try to upload and convert file to spreadsheet using this code:

GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = nil;
    self.driveFile = [[GTLDriveFile alloc]init];

```
NSData *dat = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:root]];
uploadParameters =
[GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:dat MIMEType:@"text/csv"];

self.driveFile.title = @"Report.csv";
GTLQueryDrive *query = nil;
if (self.driveFile.identifier == nil || self.driveFile.identifier.length == 0)
{
    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:self.driveFile
                                        uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

    query.convert = YES;   // Convert file format to spread sheet

}
else
{
    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:self.driveFile
                                                  fileId:self.driveFile.identifier
                                        uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
}
UIAlertView *alert = [DrEditUtilities showLoadingMessageWithTitle:@"While data is uploading..."
                                                         delegate:self];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                          GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                          NSError *error)
 {
    appDel.File_Id = updatedFile.identifier;
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    if (error == nil)
    {
        self.driveFile = updatedFile;

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Feel Fix" message:@"Successfully Uploaded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        [DrEditUtilities showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to save file"
                                           message:[error description]
                                          delegate:self];
    }
}];
```

For more information, please check the Official Google Documentation for Google Drive API IOS: https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_upload_parameters#properties